# Trying to add angular material i don´t know how to fix this

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve

npm ERR! While resolving: codelyzer@0.0.28

npm ERR! Found: tslint@6.1.3

npm ERR! node_modules/tslint

npm ERR!   dev tslint@"~6.1.0" from the root project

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

npm ERR! peer tslint@"^3.9.0" from codelyzer@0.0.28

npm ERR! node_modules/codelyzer

npm ERR!   dev codelyzer@"^0.0.28" from the root project

npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: tslint@3.15.1

npm ERR! node_modules/tslint

npm ERR!   peer tslint@"^3.9.0" from codelyzer@0.0.28

npm ERR!   node_modules/codelyzer

npm ERR!     dev codelyzer@"^0.0.28" from the root project

npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry

npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a temporary workaround until github.com/mgechev/codelyzer/issues/990 is resolved. Add these lines to your `package.json`:

```
"overrides": {
  "codelyzer": {
    "@angular/core": ">=14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": ">=14.0.0"
  }
}
```

This works because the codelyzer library accidentally requires Angular 9.0 - which in turn seem to requires version 0.0.28 of codelyzer.

BTW, I'm not expert on the topic. If you're an expert on the topic, correct me if I'm wrong, and I'll update my answer ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

remove package-lock.json file and do npm install again. Moreover current version of codelyzer is 6.0.2

Comment: Didn't work. i Don't know how to fix this Could not resolve dependency: peer tslint@"^3.9.0" from codelyzer@0.0.28

Comment: I've got the same problem. Try as I might, I fail to find out which package is requiring  codelyzer@0.0.28. Removing the pckage-lock.json was my first thought, but it doesn't work. If you want to try it yourself, my repository is https://github.com/stephanrauh/extended-pdf-viewer-showcase.

Comment: It might be a configuration mistake of codelyzer: https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer/issues/990